# how to process html using angular and bindings (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

here is my testing page :

```
<div ng-controller="test">
  <input ng-keyup="asIwrite($event)" />
  <p id="entityContent"></p>
</div>
```

and my controller :

```
EntitiesApp.controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.asIwrite = function ($event) {
        $('#entityContent').html($event.srcElement.value);
    }
}]);
```

this is actually working, if i write `<a href="go/here">click</a>` in the input, the paragraph will hold the clickable url (processed html).

I am using *jQuery* to update the content of the paragraph as to show html element as they render in the page..
But using *jQuery* is a work-around in my opinion.

I want to achieve that using just Angular. How can I do ?

> **note** : sure I can sweep jQuery off my project and use innerHTML of the
>   element but I want to know the way of doing that in Angular with
>   bindings. I used **ng-bind** on a paragraph element but that just
>   render the value of the textarea as is, no html process is performed.

Comment: Have you tried [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See working example below.

You are right by doubting using jQuery is the right thing to do, and as you would expect it is not. The angular way to do that is register your input into the scope using `ng-model`, and the way to display it is using the `ng-bind-html` directive. (or simply `ng-bind` if it was simple text with no HTML)

However, Angular will not allow HTML binding by default as it could be a security issue. If you are sure about what you write, you can use `$scope.trustAsHtml` as showed in my example.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('test', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.trust = function(content) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <input ng-model="content"/>
  <p ng-bind-html="trust(content)"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I could manage to make it work, thanks so much. Another question, on the explanative page of Angular's sce the example shows an explicit load of ngSanitize in the app's dependencies, however in your example, you just inject the service in the controller and this is still working. any explanation to that ?

Comment: Wait, you're right and honestly I do not explain that... Maybe, althought the documentation says otherwise, `$sce` is part of the main `angular.js` while `$sanitize` would only comes from `angular-sanitize.js`. I get a big doubt now :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably have tried to do something like this but the content doesn't come out as html

```
<input ng-model="input" />
<p id="entityContent" ng-bind-html="input"></p>
```

You need to ensure strict context escaping as described here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

---

Please keep in mind what you're saying you want to do is explicitly prevented by angular developers as a way to mitigate [XSS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.owasp.org%2Findex.php%2FCross-site_Scripting_%2528XSS%2529&ei=02MMVefZOpC3oQTF1YDoAQ&usg=AFQjCNH91h4sXod5BceA1P4MnFaR9jbLLg&bvm=bv.89060397,d.cGU) attacks

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to do that, angular is simplier than that.

```
<div ng-controller="test">
  <input ng-model="variable1" />
  <p id="entityContent">{{variable1}}</p>
</div>
```

Angular binds variables automatically. When the input's value change, the new value will be printed.